# Can Python get a Href link on page one, and then get a paragraph from page 2?

Tags: python, html, screen-scraping

I am fairly new to Python, but i was wondering if i could utilize Python and its modules. To retrieve a href from page 1, and then the first paragraph in page 2.

Q2: Also, how could I scrape the first 10 link hrefs with the same div class on page one, and then scrape the first 10 paragraphs, while looping?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe you should be able to.

Try to lookup the requests and beautifulsoup python modules.

Answer (score 1):

There are two python modules that I would use for this: [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) and [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). I would use requests to get the website raw html and then use a regex to get for example your paragraph:

```
import requests, re
site = requests.get("http://somewebsite.com").text
paragraphs = re.findall(r"<p>(.*?)</p>", site, re.DOTALL)
firstPara = paragraphs[0]
print(firstPara)
```

the requests line here is self-explanatory and the regex says look for the first `<p>` tag then the brackets mean return just this bit of `.*?` which is as many `(*)` of any charachters `(.)` up to `(?)` the closing `</p>` tag. Finally the re.DOTALL just means that it will math newlines as part of the lookup

Comment: Joe, just tried your code, however i am getting a list index out of range. on line 4 firstPara = paragraphs[0]

Comment: That would mean that the `re.findall` is not returning any matches. Could you send a link to the raw html that you are trying to match? Are you sure that there are paragraph tags in it?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using beautifulsoup would be to use the [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) module.
With the [webbrowser](https://pymotw.com/2/webbrowser/) module you can open in the default webbrowser or even specify a preferred browser to open (using the default is preferable, however, as of course there is no guarantee that the user's preference will match yours!)

So you could open a url like so:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open_new('https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting')
```

or like this:

```
import webbrowser

a = webbrowser.get('chrome') #target chrome (e.g)
a.open('https://www.stackoverflow.com')
```

Unfortunately, if you just stick a hashtag (for an anchor) onto the end of a url, webbrowser doesn't seem to like this. Instead you should define your anchor using a variable and pass it into a function as a parameter:

```
def open_anchor(self, anchor):
        """ Open selected anchor in the default webbrowser
        """
        webbrowser.open( anchor )
```

There are more webbrowser examples on this [page](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/615/webbrowser.open)

Hope this helps